# Fixed horizontal spacing in itemize environment

Tags: spacing

How can I  put space after Itemmmmmmm: etc.
I want to write

```
First Itemmmmmmm:     Value
Second Itemmmm:       Value     
third Itemmmmmmmmm:   Value
```

Currently, I'm getting

```
   \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist{itemize}{leftmargin=4em,labelsep=2em}  % global adjustment

\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
 \item First Itemmmmmmm:  Value
 \item Second Itemmmm: Value
 \item third Itemmmmmmmmm: Value
  \end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent\hspace{5cm}X

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,labelwidth=5cm,align=left,itemindent=5cm]
      \item[First Itemttttttttt]:  Value
    \item[Second Itemtt]: Value
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending a competing package. `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

Use the optional argument to `\item` to replace the bullet symbol with your text.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
      \item[First Itemttttttttt:]  Value
    \item[Second Itemtt:] Value
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I wanted First Itemttttttttt:  Value
 Second Itemtt      :  Value

Comment: @user31177 if I understand you correctly, you want to force a space in there - is that right?

Comment: @user31177 --- you might be better off with a `tabular` environment in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Would using a table be an option?

```
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
  First Itemtttttttttt & : & Value \\
  Second Itemtt & : & Value
\end{tabular}
```

Math mode could also help you, though it is a rather crude solution.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align*}
  & First Itemtttttttttt & : & Value \\
  & Second Item & : & Value
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want some empty space, you could try:
`\begin{itemize}
\item[Itemtttttt:] Value
\item[Itemtt\quad :] Value
\end{itemize}`

You can always replace the \quad with other spacing commands (`\,`, `\:`, `\;`) to get an amount of space that suits you, but you'll never get perfect alignment by padding in a proportional font.

If you want alignment, Ian Thompson's suggestion of a tabular environment is probably what you want